# How do you customize the comments.template for perl-support plugin in vim?

Tags: perl, vim

I'm trying to customized the comments.template that generates something like following when I create a new `*.pl` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#===============================================================================
#
#         FILE: test.pl
#
#        USAGE: ./test.pl  
#
#  DESCRIPTION: 
#
#      OPTIONS: ---
# REQUIREMENTS: ---
#         BUGS: ---
#        NOTES: ---
#       AUTHOR: ME (me), my@email.com
# ORGANIZATION: 
#      VERSION: 1.0
#      CREATED: 02/10/2017 02:27:43 PM
#     REVISION: ---
#===============================================================================

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
```

I've been able to personalize it but I want to modify the output so a different set of packages are `use`d. I tried copying comments.template file into my template directory at `.vimrc/templates` but it's getting ignored. I tried logging in and then logging back out and that didn't help either. I looked through the vim-support documentation and didn't see anything that helped. Thanks.

Comment: *"I've been able to personalize it"* I don't follow this part...if you were able to personalize it, what's the problem? Are you saying you were able to change the comment block but not the `use` statements?

Comment: Instead of that ugly block of comments that typically gets ignored by the next guy you should maybe use POD and write proper documentation.

Comment: There is a wizard that lets you add your name and email. I generated the template using the wizard and once I finished the wizard it automatically populated my name/email into the template. And I can't get rid of the comments until I know how to override the template.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like you don't override them as I assumed. You just go into `~/.vim/bundle/perl-support/perl-support/templates` and modify them directly. I've made a backup of the original template as well as to and my custom template in case upgrades to the plugin override my custom template.

Comment: I upgraded `perl-support` plugin and my template was left in tact. So it must be the proper way of doing it.